# How to display a hide indeterminate circular progress bar in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Hello am not to familiar with html and JavaScript. Am using them because map v3 is available only in JavaScript. How do set an indeterminate circular progress bar to display when my map is loading with function initialize and to turn it off after loading.

Comment: Are you working on phonegap?

Comment: No am using javascript api on android webview

Answer (score 1):

Make a GIF loading image here - http://www.ajaxload.info/ 
and download it. Then upload it to your webserver.

Then just show it during loading and hide it when complete. Let's say that the image has an ID of loadingIMG:

```
<img src='path/to/image.gif' id='loadingImg' />

//During Loading
$('#loadingImg').show();

//After done loading
$('#loadingImg').hide();

/////////////////// OR for fade in and out //////////////////

//During Loading
$('#loadingImg').fadeIn();

//After done Loading
$('#loadingImg').fadeOut();
```

Or since you indicated you want the progress element:

```
<progress id='progressbar' val='0' max='1000' ></progress>
<p id='loadingTxt' style='display: none;'>Loading Location...</p>

//When it is loading...
//Show the loading text
$('#loadingTxt').show();

//During loading, just have dummy progress
var timer = setInterval(function(){ 

     //Incriment Progress bar
     $('#progressbar').attr('value',parseInt($('#progressbar').attr('value'))+10);
}, 1000);

//When completed, set bar to full
//Stop timer,
clearInterval(timer);

//Set to full,
$('#progressbar').attr('value',1000);

//Hide the loading text
$('#loadingTxt').hide();
```

Just adjust the max val to meet the needs of how fast it loads.

Comment: does that mean I can't use progress tag, that is normally used in html

Comment: Check out my addition to the comment, does that help?

Comment: please can a text be attached to it like "loading location"

Comment: Sure, just added a paragraph that you can show during loading and hide after loading.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it didn't work, may be am missing something. Can you please give a complete working example, am a novice in html and JavaScript or refer me to a page for concise explanation

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes

Comment: I tried to post the code, but is too long. Just give me an example on how to display gif animation or indeterminate circular progress bar that starts rotating when a button is clicked and ends when the method function finishes running

Comment: check your mail, I have sent it

Comment: Did you modify it at all?

Comment: can you please look at the code again. I don't understand why JavaScript doesn't have a simple indeterminate circular loader like native android. I tried everything I can to fix this problem but is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use *.gif image on state loading, and remove it after map load. You don't need any animation, just create it in gif. Or Use othe image and rotate it via css or js.

Comment: please can you give me an instance, this part is giving me sleepless night. Time is running out